# Get string between specific character

Tags: c#, string, uwp

I have a string: "https://mhnkp2.com/src/vid/pra/Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4"

I want to get only "Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah"

I try to use code:

```
string path = "https:\/\/mhnkp2.com\/src\/vid\/pra\/Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4"
int start = path.IndexOf("/") + 5;
int end = path.IndexOf(".", start);
string result = path.Substring(start, end - start);
```

But the result is only "kp". How to handle it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and better describe your problem. Show more example input and output. Do the URLs always have this exact pattern? What problem did you try to solve with `+ 5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("https://mhnkp2.com/src/vid/pra/Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of these ways :

First, separate the string part :

```
var originalValue = @"https://mhnkp2.com/src/vid/pra/Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4";

        var startPoint = originalValue.LastIndexOf('/') + 1 ;
        var endPoint = originalValue.Length - startPoint;
        var splitedValue = originalValue.Substring(startPoint, endPoint);
        var dotIndex = splitedValue.LastIndexOf('.');
        var extension = splitedValue.Substring(dotIndex, splitedValue.Length - dotIndex);

        var finalValue = splitedValue.Replace(extension, string.Empty);
```

Second, using .Net library :

```
var result = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("https://mhnkp2.com/src/vid/pra/Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't get only string started from last `/`

```
string s =  "https:\/\/mhnkp2.com\/src\/vid\/pra\/Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4";
string lastSegment = s.Split('/').Last();
```

so, you can get `Tentang_Mata-Cerita_Boneka-Prasekolah.mp4` and remove l'extension to get file name